# Mongoose - how to update only specific fields in an object - findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm struggling with this one for a long time and I don't know how to figure it out.

I have this item that is sent to mutation editItem

```
{
  "data": {
    "editItem": {
      "id": "62379097ad992c518497f0f0",
      "itemDate": "2022-03-24T00:00:00",
      "itemName": "laptop",
      "itemCategory": {
        "categoryName": "laptops",
        "categoryType": "electronic"
      },
      "itemPrice": {
        "price": "1000",
        "currency": "GBP"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

And let's say that I want to change `itemCategory.categoryType` and `itemPrice.price`, so the action should only update respective two fields.

Code I'm using:

```
    editItem: async (_, args, context) => {
      const currentUser = await checkAuthorization(context)

      let { itemDate, itemName, itemCategory, itemPrice } =
        args.itemInput

      if (itemDate) {
        itemDate = dayjs(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
      }
      if (itemPrice) {
        itemPrice = { ...itemPrice, price: itemPrice.price }
      }
      if (itemCategory) {
        itemCategory = {
          ...itemCategory,
          categoryType: itemCategory.categoryType,
        }
      }
      if (itemDate || itemName || itemCategory || itemPrice) {
        const currentDate = dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
        const itemBody = await Item.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: args.itemID },
          {
            $set: {
              itemDate: itemDate,
              itemName: itemName,
              itemCategory: {
                categoryName: itemCategory.categoryName,
                categoryType: itemCategory.categoryType,
              },
              itemPrice: {
                price: itemPrice.price,
                currency: itemPrice.currency,
              },
            },
          },
          { upsert: true, new: true },
        )
        return itemBody
      }
    },
```

typeDefs:

```
type Item {
  id: ID!
  itemDate: String
  itemName: String!
  itemCategory: Category
  itemPrice: Price!
}

input ItemInput {
  itemDate: String
  itemName: String
  itemCategory: CategoryInput
  itemPrice: PriceInput
}

input CategoryInput {
  categoryName: String
  categoryType: String
}

input PriceInput {
  price: String!
  currency: String
}

type Mutation {
  editItem(itemID: ID!, itemInput: ItemInput): Item!
}
```

I send this request, however it puts both categoryName and currency to null

```
{
  "itemId": "62379097ad992c518497f0f0",
  "itemInput": {
    "itemCategory": {
      "categoryType": "newType"
    },
    "itemPrice": {
      "price": "500"
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "editItem": {
      "id": "62379097ad992c518497f0f0",
      "itemDate": "2022-03-24T00:00:00",
      "itemName": "laptop",
      "itemCategory": {
        "categoryName": null,
        "categoryType": "newType"
      },
      "itemPrice": {
        "price": "500",
        "currency": null
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how to update the code in order to keep the fields as they were before? Meaning that categoryName and currency won't be overwritten?

Comment: Because you are setting categoryType and currency in the code, but not passing in values, they are being set to null when you do the update. You either need to pass in values for those fields, or not have the fields in the update.

Comment: OK so is there no other way then loading the existing values first and then comparing them with the `args` values and deciding which can be re-used(the ones not requested in the update)? I wanted to prevent this situation, is there no way to just update one field within the object, for example the `price` without having to load the `itemID` first?

Comment: The other option is to not have `categoryType: itemCategory.categoryType` and `currency: itemPrice.currency` in your $set. If you don't include those fields, they won't get overwritten. If you include them, then you need to have the original value